# Get Data From XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML file getting from the result of a stored procedure.xml file like

```
<filters><TT TXT1="Electronics" /><TT TXT1="Computer" /><TT TXT1="HP" /></filters>
```

I getting this by the stored procedure in XSLT is

```
<xsl:variable name="p" select="get:GetProductFromId(get:UrlInformation()//productid)" />
    <xsl:text>» </xsl:text>
              <xsl:variable name="Breadcrumb" select="get:ExecStoredProcedure('kt_Brdcrumb',concat('@Dcat:',$p//defaultcategory))"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable  name="Txt" select="XSLTHelper:FiltersToXML($Breadcrumb)">

      </xsl:variable>
```

My need is to print the getting data in the XML in below format

```
Electronics >>  Computer >> HP
```

I tried something like this..but didn't get

```
 <xsl:for-each select="$Txt/Column1/TT">
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:for-each>
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 2):

One reason your example doesn't work is the `Column1` between `$Txt` and `TT`.

In hindsight, I'm not sure why I used the recursive template in my other answer. The following solution produces the same results and is much simpler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="filters">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TT"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TT">
    <xsl:value-of select="@TXT1"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text> &gt;&gt; </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this input XML:

```
<filters>
   <TT TXT1="Electronics" />
   <TT TXT1="Computer" />
   <TT TXT1="HP" />
</filters>
```

the following XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="filters">
    <xsl:call-template name="print">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="TT"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This template uses recursion on the list of TT elements to print them 
       one-by-one, treating the last one differently. -->
  <xsl:template name="print">
    <xsl:param name="items"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- Check that we have some items to print. -->
      <xsl:when test="not($items)"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$items/@TXT1"/>
        <!-- If we haven't reached the last one yet, print a couple of
             greater-than signs and keep going. -->
        <xsl:if test="count($items) &gt; 1">
          <xsl:text> &gt;&gt; </xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="print">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[not(position()=1)]"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output text:

```
Electronics >> Computer >> HP
```